# Filter out columns that contain NULL values in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm working with SQL Server 2008. 
I have a select statement that always return a single row. I want to wrap it with another select statement that will return the same row but will filter out all of the columns that have null values.
For example, if the first select statement returned:

```
C1     C2     C3     C4     C5
----------------------------------
1       2    NULL   NULL     5
```

The second will filter out columns C3 and C4 and I'll get:

```
C1      C2      C5
-------------------
1       2        5
```

Is that possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

In the second case, just don't include `C3` and `C4` in your `SELECT` statements - that's really all you can do.

There's no *magic* option in T-SQL to leave out **columns** that are `NULL` - either you want the column and then you specify it in your `SELECT` list of columns, or you don't want it - then leave it out.

Comment: The above was an example, the set of columns which contain non null values can be different every time, so I can't just hard code the column names.

Comment: Then you can not filter them out. SImple. It has t obe done in the SQL statement. Mostly because SQL Server returns data BEFORE PROCESSSING ALL OF IT - so it never knows whether a not null value may come further down the line for a column.

Answer (score 2):

This is really a job for the front end not T-SQL

That said, it can be done with dynamic SQL but it is much easier to do it from whatever front-end calls this select statement

Comment: The problem is that I don't control the front end, I just need to provide a SQL query.

Comment: @user1039580: And are you certain that the front end expects the number of columns in the result set to vary?

Answer (score 0):

Well why don't you create a view with not null values like

```
create view vnotnull as select C1,C2,C5 from your_table
```

Comment: because I am sure the columns that are NULL are not always the same

Comment: well, if they always contains NULL then it's the best way filter out them. then you use the view to get only not null cols. ISn't it?

Comment: No.even if you do `select a from view where a is not null` and a is null you will get back at least an empty resultset

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help or not, but it almost sounds like UNPIVOT might be worth a look.  It returns column values as different rows.

```
declare @t table(c1 int, c2 int, c3 int, c4 int, c5 int)

insert into @t(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) values (1,2,null, null, 5)

select cols, col
from (select c1,c2,c3,c4,c5 from @t) p
unpivot (cols for col in (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)) as unpvt
```

Returns:

```
cols        col
----------- ---------
1           c1
2           c2
5           c5
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!